# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer not found

Tags: classnotfoundexception, wildfly-8, omnifaces, arquillian-drone

My problem probably looks like duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811971/java-util-serviceconfigurationerror-when-running-tests-using-arquillianomniface) question. (But I don't consider the answer posted there as its solution) ie. when Omnifaces-2.1 dependency is added into my application's POM, then the Arquillian-Drone testing on Wildfly 8.2.0.Final Embedded Container fails with following error/exception trace.

```
WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.omnifaces.VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension from [Module "deployment.service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:131) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:117) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:81) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]

WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeExtension: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeExtension from [Module "deployment.service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:131) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:117) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:81) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]

WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerExtension: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerExtension from [Module "deployment.service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:131) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:117) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:81) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]

WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.omnifaces.cdi.param.ParamExtension: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.cdi.param.ParamExtension from [Module "deployment.service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:131) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:117) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:81) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."service.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."service.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "service.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

This trace suggests, Omnifaces library is not loaded while creating test archive, but why?
However, the same configuration of POM works perfectly on Wildfly 8.2.0.Final Remote and Managed test containers. I insist on getting a solution for  Wildfly 8.2.0.Final Embedded container. Has anybody completed a workaround for this problem ?

Comment: If it is a dupe, don't ask the same question -- set a bounty on the original one

Comment: As I insisted earlier, the answer posted there is not real solution to our concrete problem. So, for now it looks, we should avoid testing on WildFly-Embedded container?

Comment: Nope, you just need to make sure that OmniFaces is placed in Arquillian's runtime classpath. I don't do Arquillian, so I can't go in detail, but Arjan T says that it's simply missing in Arquillian's runtime classpath.

Comment: Thank you guys for your rapid response on the topic. I will seek a way through according to your clue.

Comment: did you find any way to fix that issue? I have a same problem.